# How to iterate through specific object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to reduce amount of IF statements in my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/b0ftLujj/

Too many properties are repeated which is a problem.

Second part which may relate to the code above.
I would like to iterate through my object properties:

`myObject ={
  property_1: myValue_1,
  property_2: myValue_2,
  otherProperty_1: myValue_1
};`

Based on an object above, I want to iterate only through `property_1, property_2`, ignoring `otherProperty_1`.

My object can have "property_x" properties up to 5 of them, or none at all. I was trying to make an if statement which would be something like this pseudo code:

```
for(var statName in myObject){
  If(myObject has any property called : 'property_1, property_2, property_3, property_4, property_5'.indexOf(statName) != -1;)
    //Then display in html: '<img src="images/' + property_x(where x is a property 1/2/3/4 or 5) and it would display only available properties in current object. I can make it work with an 5x if else statements to check for every property, since there cannot be property_1 and property_3/4/5 if "2" is missing. I was looking for a better way to display it.
  }
}
```

Answer using JavaScript would be the best, but jQuery us an option too.
Any links with material I can use to learn more are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the second part of your question, but here's a simplified version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0ftLujj/):

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
if (dropItem.itemType === "weapon") {
  dropItem["materiaSlot_1"] = 'empty';
  if (randomNumber >= 40) dropItem["materiaSlot_2"] = 'empty';
  if (randomNumber >= 60) dropItem["materiaSlot_3"] = 'empty';
  if (randomNumber >= 80) dropItem["materiaSlot_4"] = 'empty';
  if (randomNumber >= 95) dropItem["materiaSlot_5"] = 'empty';
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks :) Thats what I was looking for. About second problem check my comment reply below, it should explain it a bit better I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i fully understand, but your pseudocode is actually pretty much valid :-). You can iterate through each object properties using `for prop in obj` statement ( you should also check if it's object own property ), and get the value of this property using `obj[prop]` code.

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        html += '<img src="' + obj[prop] + '" />';
    }
}
```

Here's the fiddle for that http://jsfiddle.net/b0ftLujj/1/

Comment: Hey I know about this code but the problem is that, my object has about 30 properties, I want to check if it has those certain properties "property_1, property_2, property_3, property_4, property_5" and run the code based on those properties, so it would be similar to your code but would search only for those properties. I hope you can understand it better now :P

Comment: And you know those parameters by name? Why don't you simple iterate through them. http://jsfiddle.net/b0ftLujj/2/

Comment: Hey, I dont have enough experience to come with that solution, thanks alot that will work for me. Actually...now that I look at my code I did exactly same thing lol ._. well almost the same, still your code takes less space so it's better than mine.